# Añadir "noindex" en un enlace a un pdf

Tags: php, html, seo, mpdf

Tengo una web en la que tengo enlaces a un script `php` donde genero un `pdf` con la librería [mPdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) y se visualiza en el navegador o se descarga, depende de la configuración.

El problema es que no quiero que se indexe en `google`. Ya he puesto en el enlace `rel="nofollow"` con eso ya no se indexa, ¿pero como puedo hacer para que se dexindexe los que ya hay?

Con `rel="noindex, nofollow"` no funciona.

Tendría que hacerlo unicamente por `php` o algún tag `html` ya que por `htaccess` no me sirve.

Comment: cada pdf generado tiene una url específica?

Comment: En la url mando unos parametros especificos y en función de esos parametros se genera un pdf u otro @aloMalbarez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

agrega en el script php el header tag no-index (justo antes de enviar el pdf)

```
header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet");

...
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

para tenerlo disponible por un tiempo (podes indicar una fecha en el pasado para reafirmar el noarchive)

```
header("X-Robots-Tag: noarchive");
header("X-Robots-Tag: unavailable_after: 25 Jun 2018 15:00:00 PST");
```

en .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ".pdf$">
   Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"
</FilesMatch>
```

ref:
https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag?hl=es

Answer (score 3):

Para "desindexar" url's debes acceder a ésta página https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal y darlas de baja de google.

> **Conseguir una eliminación permanente**
>
> La Herramienta para eliminar URLs
>   solo establece eliminaciones temporales. Para eliminar de forma
>   permanente contenido o URLs de la Búsqueda de Google, debes realizar
>   al menos una de las siguientes acciones adicionales:
>
> - Eliminar o actualizar el contenido real de tu sitio web (imágenes, páginas y directorios) y asegurarte de que el servidor web devuelve un
>     código de estado HTTP 404 (página no encontrada) o bien 410 (no
>     disponible). Los archivos que no sean HTML (como los PDF) se deben
>     eliminar por completo de tu servidor. Más información sobre los
>     códigos de estado HTTP
> - Bloquear el acceso al contenido, por ejemplo, solicitando una contraseña.
> - Indicar que la página no se debe indexar utilizando una metaetiqueta noindex. Este método es menos seguro que los otros.

Te dejo la [documentación](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=es).

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. ¿No hay una forma automática de hacerlo? esque habrá unas 600 páginas que dexindexar

Comment: Se supone que cuando el bot de google revise tu página, actualizará su estado, pero no puedes forzarlo creo, tocará esperar.

Comment: Exacto, tal como dice @track3r con la etiqueta noindex indicaremos a google que no indexe la página.